# Is RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod called always?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm following this tutorial steps:
https://learn.unity.com/project/2d-roguelike-tutorial?uv=5.x

The code shown in the videos and in this web is different from the code that is downloadable. Inside this downloadable code there is a call to **RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod** in a class that is never invoked. I created a dummy class with this call and the code inside is executing too. My question is that it doesn't matter where this function is called from, it is always executed?. This is the code and no matter if I paste in a unused class. The log is always shown:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.AfterSceneLoad)]
static public void AnyFunctionName()
{
    Debug.Log("You always will see this msg");
}
```

In this case, the message is shown every time a scene is loaded.

I'm just trying to understand how this method works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, let's break things down. If you're watching tutorials and trying to learn Unity, there might be a few things you need to know. Even if you do know them, I am also considering other people reading your question (and this answer) that might not know all details. So, get ready for some history lessons (I'll try to skip the dinosaur period :) no worries). If you want to skip the history lesson and jump straight to what you need to know, read the last sub-chapter.

**The background**

While at first glance Unity seems to be an engine running on C#, it is in fact one built on top of C and C++. So everything you "see" and the way it "reacts" is coded there. This includes audio, rendering, physics and more. This is what is called the "native layer" (you'll hear about it in videos done by Unity Technologies - the company behind the Unity products, which I'll call UT for short). In technical terms, this is a lower level layer.

On top of that, we have C# code. This is running on top of the engine and the language "rules" behind it are part of the `.NET Standard`. This is called the "managed layer". There is not `.ASP`, no `.NET Framework`, no `.NET Core`, nothing of what you would know of the Microsoft implementation for Windows. You can call the framework behind the C# implementation "The Unity API". And yes, there are options to use *some* libraries that are part of the `.NET Framework`. The managed layer is running over the Mono Runtime as opposed to Windows .NET apps that run on top of .NET.

**Messages**

Let's move on to the fun stuff now. Engine events (like when the components starts, when the game quits etc.) is done using what UT call "messages" (they don't call them events as to not confuse them with C# events which are a totally different animal). They are called on instances (meaning GameObjects that are instantiated and have `Components` that listen to that specific game event, aka *message*; meaning, that if you don't have an `Update()` function, Unity will not try to call it and end up calling "nothing", it just won't call it). There are also some C# events that you can subscribe to (for example in `UnityEngine.Application`, you can subscribe to the `quitting` C# event).

**Other types of calls**

Obviously, there are also other ways to "make" the C++ Engine call your own custom C# methods, as you found out. Using the attribute `RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute` is the main one. So what exactly happens on the native side? There are different stages in the Player's execution (**player** in this context means the Unity Player, meaning the application container that runs your game when you build it, i.e. the finished built product; inside the Unity Editor you have a simplified Player version called "Play Mode" that works 99% identical to the built version; minor personal note, `UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs` has the same context: saving Unity Player options such as audio volume, graphics settings etc., it does **NOT** mean "Human player", i.e. the character of a game or a game controller or you as a participant; just wanted to get that out of the way as many beginners confuse this and almost no YT video explains this).

Obviously there are some internal initializations, but once they're done they "start" the C# runtime and therefore the layer on which your game is running. If you'll read the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html) you'll see a high-level explanation of the steps.

Now, let's understand the rules. The attribute `RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute` can **ONLY** be applied to static methods. It will not work on instance methods. (the explanation is simple: there is no object instance to run it on, as static members, that is the variables and methods, are not "bound" to an instance, but are "global" to any occurrence of that class / type). Next, you need to understand how static variables and methods are executed in C# in general.

The major caveat you need to remember is there is no order. So, for example, if you have 3 classes and each has a static variable or property with different values, there is no guarantee that in 20 executions of your program (so we're not limiting to Unity, but it applies to C#, C, C++ and so on as a general rule) each of the 3 variables get initialized (or set) in the same order. Same rule for methods. That means **you should never ever** have sensitive code in your game that has dependencies in static functions as your game (or even any type of app) might work in *some* situations, but not in others because of the random order of execution.

Also note that while static variables will get set, static functions will not be called by default, hence the need for this attribute (`RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute`) to be "applied".

So for short: Unity scans your project and makes a list of all classes that have this attribute applied to static methods (the items are added randomly), and calls them. Also, it does this on multiple steps as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html).

Why you would need such a workflow? In most cases you won't. I can tell you I do use it with a `AfterAssembliesLoaded` parameter, to load my "main manager" (basically it instantiates a prefab using the `Resources` class). One other I might see is hooking logging functions to create your own logging system (i.e. a new file or sending them to a server or whatnot). Another use-case I can think of is maybe setting some static event callbacks. So apart from some early init, I don't see other use-cases.

If we look at the project code, we indeed see its the last use-case (callback init):

```
    //this is called only once, and the paramter tell it to be called only after the scene was loaded
    //(otherwise, our Scene Load callback would be called the very first load, and we don't want that)
    [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.AfterSceneLoad)]
    static public void CallbackInitialization()
    {
        //register the callback to be called everytime the scene is loaded
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }
```

You say *My question is that it doesn't matter where this function is called from, it is always executed?. This is the code and no matter if I paste in a unused class. The log is always shown:*

Well, the function is called by the engine when this attribute is applied. It doesn't matter if *you* call it or not in a separate piece of code. I recommend you read-up on C# static methods, fields and maybe try reading about attributes as well.

Minor note: the videos you are watching are **VERY** old (8 years). I recommend watching newer ones. As a warning, UT have a tendency to do a lot of experimental features in their engines which might or might not work, which they'll improve or not, or might even remove after a while. So not everything is the same (as you also noticed). So if you think "what could have possibly changed in 8 years, I mean the basics are the same, right?". Well, sort of. As a simple example, the way you make projects isn't even done from inside the Editor anymore, but from the Hub. Other changes: a lot of pre-installed stuff is removed and is optional and you need to install from the Package Manager (which is not the same as the Asset Store). A lot of libraries and dependencies are removed or no longer work in newer Unity versions, so a direct migration from a Unity version that is 8 years old to say, Unity 2022, might not even work out of the box. A lot of `Component` options in the Inspector, fields, methods are changed. And the list goes on. If you want, we can also discuss about which version you should use and why and pros and cons of each.